# Parse java file in maven to create separate file with identifiers and line numbers

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to make it easy for my non-developers to locate certain exceptions in my code and so I want to figure out if there is a way I can have maven search through my source as it is being built, pick out these specific exceptions and add them with the source code file name and line number to a separate file.  For instance this code:

```
throw new MyException("1234-ABCDEF-1234-CDEF45");
```

would add an entry in a file in the JAR when I compiled that would look like this:

```
1234-ABCDEF-1234-CDEF45,com\me\test\MyJavaFile.java,267
```

With that information, if my support staff has "1234-ABCDEF-1234-CDEF45" as an error they could cross reference that value in the file and know the file/line number.  BTW I understand that printing the stack trace to the log would also give them this information, but I am purposely not printing the stack trace to the log file because these happen a lot and are excepted in the normal flow of the program.